# Why Kubernetes Egress Not Working Properly on Worker?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I Have 1 master and 2 work kubernetes cluster,
i  am running application on that cluster but pods
running on the worker node is not able to connect to the internet
and i am also enable egress network policy for all pods.
this is my network policy

````
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all-egress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress: 
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress```
````

Comment: where is your cluster is deployed AWS, GCP private public subnet ?  which POD network are you using ? your core DNS working did you checked logs ? Provide the full details.

Comment: i deployed my cluster in a dedicated server. i checked my coredns too and it is also running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use weave-net or calico network addon for pod communication

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-all-traffic
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - {}
```

https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/02a-allow-all-traffic-to-an-application.md

Comment: i allow ingress for all pods but still not working.

Comment: that's weird hope you are applying to proper namespace

Comment: Actually i am using OVN4NFV-K8S-Plugin add-on and i tried other addon like weave-net 
in my another kubernetes cluster it is working without ingress and egress network policy.
Is there any chance that differs because fo this addons?